# Intellij PyCharm interface usage

Tags: intellij-idea

I need to make the control from the my program the Intellij PyCharm interface. For example, select a PyCharm menu and click on some menu items. Another example : open a file and write a line there, scroll the file open on the screen up or down. How can this be done quickly?

Answer (score 0):

You can try [intellij-ui-test-robot](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-ui-test-robot).

> This library allows you to write and execute UI tests among IntelliJ Idea.